# Getting textual input from a menubar app? Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, agent, nsmenuitem, macos

So I created a menubar app (agent application) and I need to find some way to get textual input via the menubar icon. I heard that making a popup modal with a textfield is frowned upon, and putting a text field in an `NSMenuItem` is bad for functionality. It doesn't even work, when I try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new [`NSPopOver`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API in Lion. It will create a non-modal window anchored to a particular location, which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.